# Spark & Maven: SecurityException: Invalid Signature file digest for Manifest

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am running into an issue with the following error when submitting my Spark application that is copy and pasted below. I did some googling first on the issue and determining it was likely an issue with a signature jar that was being loaded as a dependency on my jar build process.  So I altered my POM to filter and remove it from the dependencies.  However even after I did that the jar still seems to be reporting back Invalid Signature file digest.

I am building my jar via Build > Build Artifacts via IntelliJ IDE.
I created my artifact via File > Project Structure > Artifacts > Extract to the target Jar.

Has anyone compiled a Spark application in Maven & the intellij IDE and provide me steps with how to do this properly?

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main att                                                                                                                     ributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVeri                                                                                                                     fier.java:286)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier                                                                                                                     .java:239)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:307)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:218)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:345)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:412)
    at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:674)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:666)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:665)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:638)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:366)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:356)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:355)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:332)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:198)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.analysis</groupId>
<artifactId>sentiment</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>SENTIMENTTWITTER</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>resource.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.verizon.npi.sentiment.MainApp</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved my issue.  The issue was the way I was building my application.  Instead of building it through the intellij artifact build process, You should instead build it by executing a maven goal command "mvn package".  This will build your mvn package with the filter criteria specified in the POM.xml.

The Filter from my POM still applies, in the event anyone else has problems with signature jars being pushed as a dependency to their jar that filter I have in the POM will remove them.

Answer (score 2):

To delete the META-INF* file manually, there is another try: zip -d .jar META-INF/*.RSA META-INF/*.DSA META-INF/*.SF